# Can JTable cell edit consume key strokes?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, keystroke, jmenu

In my program, there is a JMenu with many accelerators, and a JTable that is editable. Problem is, when editing the JTable, the accelerator keys still get triggered.

E.g., if I enter the letter 'n' into the jtable cell, the 'next' menu option fires as well.

How would one go about making the jtable cell editor consume the keystrokes exclusively?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class SampleClass{

    public SampleClass(){

       JFrame frame = new JFrame();
       JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
       JMenu menu = new JMenu();
       JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem();
       item.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N, 0));
       item.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            }
        });
        JTable table = new JTable(new Object[][]{{"Hello","World"},{"Goodbye","World"}}, new String[]{"A","B"});    
           menu.add(item);
           menuBar.add(menu);
           frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);           
           frame.add(table);
           frame.pack();
           frame.show();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
             new SampleClass();
        } 
}
```

Edit any cell in the above table, there's a menu item set to beep with the accelerator 'n'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug (which I thought had been fixed ages ago ... tsssee) due to a rather weird key processing of JTable. It starts editing in processKeyBinding on a pressed keyEvent - if autoStartEdits is true, as it is by default - and then passes that key on to the editingComponent. So at the end of the day, the key is consumed if the editingComponent consumes it. TextComponents consume a key on typed, not pressed ... which allows the pressed to travel up the dispatch chain until it reaches the menu.

A hackaround (beware: all hacks are dirty and might have unforeseen/unforseable side-effects!) is to override the table's processKeyBinding and consume the key if it started an edit:

```
@Override
protected boolean processKeyBinding(KeyStroke ks,
        KeyEvent e, int condition, boolean pressed) {
    boolean result = super.processKeyBinding(ks, e, condition, pressed);
    if (isEditing() && pressed) return true;
    return result;
}
```